# In a drawing app based on vectors, how could you calculate all distinct closed regions when the user adds a freehand path to the drawing?

Tags: drawing, shapes, vector-graphics

I'm looking to implement something similar to how Flash drawing worked. As follows:

1. The user uses the freehand drawing tool to draw an arbitrary path.
2. On finish of each path, the app calculates all distinct closed regions on the drawing canvas, which includes parts of the recent path that overlap itself, as well as intersections with existing shape paths on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to take a stab at answering my own question.

One approach I can see is to create a graph where all intersection points between strokes are nodes, which have pointers to neighbor intersection points. (Not literal pointers as I'm implementing this in Javascript). Neighbors would be the next intersection points on each path in the intersection.

When adding a new path to the drawing, we would check for intersections with all existing paths, and if found, would decorate those points as nodes, pointing them at neighbors, and adding/updating neighbors to point at the new points.

Then, for each new intersection point, we'd follow the graph looking for cycles, first checking every right-hand path, then every left-hand path. If a path hits an endpoint to a drawing path, we return false for that intersection point.

I'm not sure how to ignore the case of the outermost path -- if the intersection points on the outer edge of the drawing form a cycle, though this would be rare in practice.

I think this approach works, but would love to know if there's a simpler one.